# Car rental USA Seattle -> Las Vegas

Tags: usa, car-rentals, automobiles, rental

I would like to ask, what is the best option for renting car in USA.

I am 25 years old. My friends are 24 and 23 years old. We wanted to take care from Seattle to return it back in Las Vegas. There are some problems I run into.

-> We do not have credit cards (only debet)
-> I am going to leave them in Los Angeles at the middle of trip
-> We would like to minimalize under 25 years old fee
-> We want to have two additional drivers

There are two options
1) We take car at Seattle, WA on 30th April and return it on 13th May in Las Vegas, Nv - 2 additional drivers, I am upsent from 6th May
2) We take car at Seattle, WA on 30th April and return it on 6th May at Los Angeles, CA and take other car from LA, CA and return it on 13th May at Las Vegas - 1 additional driver, in second route the main driver is under 25 years old.

What can you propose for me?

Comment: sure, just do Option 2.  it saves you a few dollars, and you'll want to go to the airport anyway.  plus, it's fun to change cars!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will find this good enough

I already worked with **Alamo Rent A Car**, they were great!
As i remember the age is not a problem, but they are asking to pay insurance 
supplement.

Please check the [terms and conditions](https://www.alamo.com/en_US/car-rental/checkin/terms-and-conditions.html), you can pay with debit but you need to give a deposit.

Comment: Alamo does not support debet cards, at least as we have spoken with them by phone.

Comment: I will check another company for you.

Comment: **Does Thrifty accept debit cards for payment?**
Debit cards may be used to qualify at the start of the rental however there are some restrictions regarding the use of a Debit Card, please refer to the General Policies section for specific information regarding the debit card policy at the Thrifty Location where you intend to rent.  In most cases, the location will perform a credit check to determine credit worthiness at time of rental.  Debit card and prepaid or store value cards are accepted for payment at the end of your rental.  Please see the General Policies section.

Comment: https://www.thrifty.com/customercare/content/faq.aspx#22